# Struct strange in pure C

Tags: c, struct

I just read a open source. In it, I see a some code, it make me unfamiliar. So it is something about the struct:

```
struct _NameStruct;

typedef struct _NameStruct NameStruct
```

And after that, they (open source) use NameStruct to contain some variable. I wonder Why struct _NameStruct not yet define some variable so how they can use it?

Comment: Check the include files to see it's define

Comment: @Invoker: the definition is required only when you need to assign to the members of the struct or when you need the sizeof the struct, etc. To declare a pointer to it, this detail is not required since the sizeof a pointer will be based on the platform and not on the struct and is thus allowed.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the code carefully, you'll probably find they only ever use a pointer to the data type. It's probably an opaque data type so you can pass around a pointer to it but not actually have to know how it is implemented.

These are usually used for things like handles where only the library needs to know the implementation of the struct.